# python get unix timestamp given a timezone and datetime

Tags: python-3.x

is there a simplified way to get unix timestamp given a timezone and datetime using datetime and pytz? 
I searched some answers but not exactly this case.

Given the moment `datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 15, 22, 0, 0)` in tz `Asia/Tokyo`, goal is to get the unix timestamp of that moment.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a 3rd-party library to convert `'Asia/Tokyo'` into a proper timezone. The most common one used is the [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) library as follows:

```py
import datetime

import pytz


naive_datetime = datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 15, 22, 0, 0)
new_datetime = naive_datetime.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))
```

`new_datetime` will now yield `datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 16, 5, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Asia/Tokyo' JST+9:00:00 STD>)`

Then you use the `timestamp` method on the datetime to get the UTC UNIX timestamp:

```py
>>> new_datetime.timestamp()
1584302400.0
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1584302400.0)
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 15, 20, 0)
```

You could also look into the [pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/#switching-timezones) library, which offers an all-around friendly experience dealing with times and dates.

Comment: FYI - utcfromtimestamp() is deprecated in 3.12